# Mix of text and image inside a <h1> tag

Tags: html, css

I am looking to have a mix of text and image in the title (h1). Obviously I want the image to be in the middle of the text on the same line. I don't want the image to show below the text.

```
<H1>some <img src="image.jpg" alt="image" width=20 height=20> text</H1>
```

Comment: Can add screenshot of what you want actually?

Comment: According to your code Image should be in middle and in one line unless some other styling is overriding this behavior.

Comment: Please detail more on the expectation

Comment: have you tried it, and what seems to be the problem? your code does seem to work. sample: https://jsfiddle.net/wazz/1gogL9sb/.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the hint.
the issue was actually in the css where I inherited: `width:100%;`,
which forced the image to occupied the whole width